# How to round a numpy vectorize function returned list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using `numpy.vectorize()` for my function in order to apply the function to an array, it works fine:

```
X = [-10000, -1000, -100, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
def softplus(x):
    return np.logaddexp(1.0,x)
y=numpy.vectorize(softplus)
```

The problem is that I want to use `numpy.around()` on the resulted list to round the decimal places to four but it does not effect the `print` result.

```
result = y(X)
print(numpy.around(result, decimals=4))
```

Output

```
[  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00 ...]
```

Comment: all that `vectorize` logic is redundant. Just use `np.logaddexp(1.0, X)`.

Comment: @NilsWerner True but that is not the issue afai understood

Comment: And for me the output is correct, too (`array([  ..., 1.12690000e+00,   1.31330000e+00, ... ])`). Maybe you are confusing rounding with print-formatting float values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `vectorize` here because [`np.logaddexp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html) is already a vectorized function (as is `np.around`). But the `vectorize` gives the correct result:

```
>>> np.logaddexp(1.0, X)
array([  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
         1.00001670e+00,   1.12692801e+00,   1.31326169e+00,
         1.69314718e+00,   1.00001234e+01,   1.00000000e+02,
         1.00000000e+03,   1.00000000e+04])
```

Also the `np.around` correctly rounds the results:

```
>>> np.around(np.loagaddexp(1.0, X))
array([  1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+00,   1.12690000e+00,   1.31330000e+00,
         1.69310000e+00,   1.00001000e+01,   1.00000000e+02,
         1.00000000e+03,   1.00000000e+04])
```

But if you wanted to display only 4 decimals you would need to use something else, for example [`np.array2string`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html):

```
>>> print(np.array2string(np.logaddexp(1., X), precision=4))
[  1.0000e+00   1.0000e+00   1.0000e+00   1.0000e+00   1.1269e+00
   1.3133e+00   1.6931e+00   1.0000e+01   1.0000e+02   1.0000e+03
   1.0000e+04]
```

Or in case you want to display `4` decimals you can use a custom-formatter:

```
>>> print(np.array2string(np.logaddexp(1., X), formatter={'float': '{:.4f}'.format}))
[1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.1269 1.3133 1.6931 10.0001 100.0000
 1000.0000 10000.0000]
```

or with a `seperator`:

```
>>> print(np.array2string(np.logaddexp(1., X), 
...                       formatter={'float': '{:.4f}'.format}, 
...                       separator=', '))
[1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.1269, 1.3133, 1.6931, 10.0001, 100.0000,
 1000.0000, 10000.0000]
```

Comment: Thank you MSeifert for your detailed explanation. I want the array after round up something like [1.0000, 1.0000,1.0000, 1.0000, 1.1269, 1.3133, 1.6931, 10.0001,100.0000, 1000.0000, 10000.0000]

Comment: @Sahim No problem. If it solved your problem you might want to consider accepting it. If it doesn't solve it, feel free to post another comment which part of the answer doesn't work or needs clarification :)

Comment: @Sahim ok, I updated the answer. :) It should display the desired result. :)

Comment: your answer is perfectly right. the only thing I want is that it converts the array to string but I want the array to be float so that I can access each element of the array. thanks

Comment: okay, maybe you should edit your question (or better: ask a new one) where you actually show what you want to do and how. This question seemed to be just about rounding and displaying. So I'd say you should just use `np.around(..., decimals=4)` first and when you want to have another "display" you can use `np.array2str`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the print statements are different, you will find by printing the result without the round() statement, check result[7].
the e+01 implies *10 and so forth.